# How to create a method to display the result of the following array program?

Tags: java, arrays

Below is the code that I have been able to develop- but I having trouble to create a code to display the result.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Student2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name= "";
        char[] array;
        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter a word: ");
        name= input.nextLine();
        array= tally(name);
        input.close();
    }
    public static char[] tally(String name){
        char[] charArray= name.toCharArray();
        char[] arr= name.toCharArray();

        for (int count=0; count<name.length(); count= count+1){
            arr[count]= (char)(arr[count]);
            System.out.println(name.charAt(count) +"\t"+(int)arr[count]);   
        }
        return charArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: What result are you looking to display?

Comment: the "System.out.println(name.charAt(count) +"\t"+(int)arr[count])" to be displayed using another method-

Comment: public static void displayResults(tally)
  {
   System.out.println(name.charAt(count) +"\t"+(int)arr[count]);    This is the method that i have created, but is not working

Comment: The return from the tally method is name.toCharArray(). Are you sure this is what you intended given that this is simply converting a string parameter to an array.

Comment: Yes, so far it works fine- but when I try to create another method do display the result, I am not able to --  This is my first time learning java(1st semester) so I am new at this..

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit.**

Your method:

```
     public static void displayResults(String word) {
System.out.println(tally(word));
}
```

Invoke your method from your main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String name= "";
char[] array;
Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Please enter a word: ");
name= input.nextLine();
array= tally(name);

/*Below is where I called your method:*/
displayResults("Test");
```

Your main continues:

```
input.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way you can do it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name= "";
    char[] array;
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter a word: ");
    name= input.nextLine();
    array= tally(name);
    input.close();        

    //add print statement that uses Arrays.toString()
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

Output:

```
Please enter a word: bob
b   98
o   111
b   98
[b, o, b]
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I haven't catch what your problem, but simply reading your code, you may want to display the character in a string and display the ASCII number at the same time, so the code can be wrote like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class  Student2{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a word: ");
    String name= input.nextLine();
    tally(name);
    input.close();

    }
public static void tally(String name){
    for(char ch:name.toCharArray()){
        System.out.println(ch+"\t"+(int)ch);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are correct A. Joe- but I need to implement 2 methos-  1 to determine the character tallies and the 2nd to display a table of the results-